# Accessing Nested arrays in JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json

Hey there I am trying to extract items in an array inside a json dictionary but I'm getting the below error. Thank you in advance for your help.

Error:

```
    for r in data[p]['reportDetails']:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The code snippet is below:

```
def XeroExtractReports(cred_fp):
    with open(cred_fp, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for p in data['credentials']:
            client_id = p['clientId']
            client_secret = p['clientSecret']
            old_refresh_token = p['refreshToken']

            for r in data[p]['reportDetails']:
                get_url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/' + r['reportName']
                response = requests.get(get_url,
                                       headers = {
                                           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + new_tokens[0],
                                           'Xero-tenant-id': xero_tenant_id,
                                           'Accept': 'application/json'
                                       })
                json_response = response.json()
                print(json_response)
                print('\n')
```

JSON Dictionary:

```
{
    "credentials": [{
        "clientName": "C1",
        "clientId": "null",
        "clientSecret": "null",
        "redirectUrl": "http://localhost:8080/callback",
        "scopes": "offline_access accounting.transactions.read",
        "reportType": "null",
        "refreshToken": "null",
        "reportDetails": [
            {
                "reportName": "BankTransactions",
                "reportFilename": "/BankTransactions.txt"
            },
            {
                "reportName": "BankTransfers",
                "reportFilename": "/BankTransfers.txt"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to access values on a wrong way

instead of:

```
for r in data[p]['reportDetails']:
    ...
```

use:

```
for r in p['reportDetails']:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `data[p]` to get value of `reportDetails`.

You already got the dict when you set `p`

Change the second loop with:

```py
for r in p['reportDetails']
```